# How do I convert a JSON constructed from Table to a datatable for an Update Query in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, json

I would like to send json data from a HTML table to the ASP.NET code-behind and update the data in and SQL Server database. The code and JSON for the `TableProductToUpdate()` is below.

```
function UpdateProductTable() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/UpdateProductTable",
            data: "{'products':" + JSON.stringify(TableProductToUpdate()) + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);                
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Data Updated Successfully");                
            }
        });
    }


{'products':
  "[
    {
      \"id\":\"907\", 
      \"name\":\"Rear Brakes\", 
      \"productNumber\":\"RB-9231\", 
      \"color\":\"Silver\", 
      \"stdCost\":\"47.286\", 
      \"listPrice\":\"106.5\", 
      \"size\":\"null\", 
      \"weight\":\"317\", 
      \"modelId\":\"128\"
    },
         
    {
     \"id\":\"948\", 
     \"name\":\"Front Brakes\", 
     \"productNumber\":\"FB-9873\", 
     \"color\":\"Silver\", 
     \"stdCost\":\"47.286\", 
     \"listPrice\":\"106.5\", 
     \"size\":\"null\", 
     \"weight\":\"317\", 
     \"modelId\":\"102\"}]"
    }
```

How do I consume this JSON string in JSON.NET. How do I loop through the data and construct an update query?

I have been successful in serializing the datatable to JSON using JSON.NET, but can the reverse be done?

#### Update

Tried Nathan's answer, but I get the following error:

```
{"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type
 \u0027System.Collections.Generic.List`1[_Default+Product]\u0027","StackTrace":"   
  at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, 
JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n
at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, \
Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& 
convertedObject)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 
rawParams)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, 
IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, 
WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, 
WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

#### Code-behind

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function UpdateProductTable(ByVal products As List(Of Product)) As String            
        Dim product As Product
        For Each product In products
            'Update query
        Next
        Return "Success"
    End Function

    Public Class Product
        Property id As String
        Property name As String
        Property number As String
        Property color As String
        Property stdCost As String
        Property listPrice As String
        Property size As String
        Property weight As String
        Property modelId As String
    End Class
```

Comment: show us some code which is used in the web service

Comment: doesn't the data parameter in the `$.ajax()` call expect a json object...? You've passed it as a string.

Comment: @George thanks so much for cleaning up my question format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify() is a great way to translate a JavaScript object to JSON for transmitting to a .NET service.  In this case though, it appears that you're already building the JSON before that point.  So, you won't need to JSON serialize that data a second time.

You should be able to pass that directly into a method that accepts a List, like:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/UpdateProductTable",
        data: TableProductToUpdate(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);                
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Data Updated Successfully");                
        }
    });
```

As long as the properties in your array of objects match up with the properties of your Product class, .NET will automatically handle deserializing the JSON string and instantiating your List.

Comment: you are right, there was no need to serialize my JSON string again. My code is working fine now after i changed this line:    data: "{'products':" + JSON.stringify(TableProductToUpdate()) + "}", TO    data: "{'products':" + TableDataToUpdate() + "}",. Thanks so much for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

i would generally make your page method's products parameter a list type.  obviously you would need to have a class that represents a single product for that to work, but generally asp.net will be able to take your properly formed json and put it into the list variable.  so you'd end up with something like :

```
[webmethod]
pubilc bool UpdateProductTable(list<product> products) {
  foreach (product p in products) {
    //do some stuff
  }
}
```

edit:

try to update your javascript to stringify the whole thing, so instead of what you've got up there, something like :

```
var rowData = JSON.stringify({'products':TableProductToUpdate()})
```

and then pass rowData in your ajax call. not sure if that solves the issue or not, but seems like a better way to ensure correct json.